# IOS app like Flic and Cleen but for imported images

Tags: ios, file-management, photography

I have a huge photo archive from my [DSLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_single-lens_reflex_camera) days. Now I want to clean up those since there are lots of junk and same photos. I dont have time to do it at home so I want to do it while I commute to work, on my iPhone or iPad mini.

There are lots of file manager apps around and I tried some. But what I want is a fast and easy way to do that. [Flic and cleen](http://techcrunch.com/2014/11/11/flic-and-cleen-are-tinder-for-your-photos/) does that perfectly for photos on camera rolls, but in my case I have an external photo library: I want it work offline actually and want to import photos once with iTunes or WiFi. Then when I clear unwanted photos want to import back to my PC.

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Sorry for not being more clear. I want it work offline actually and want to import photos once with iTunes or WiFi. Then when I clear unwanted photos want to import back to my pc

Comment: Thanks for the update! I've integrated that into your question directly (remember you always can [edit] your post to improve, fix, or add new details ;) Good luck then – I cannot further help on this, being from the "other side" (Android) ;)